# Split string to list of objects

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have a String like below with three or four values seperated by `|||`, so when split on `|||` it can give three string single pipe seperated or four strings pipe seperated

```
james|12343|ascxZCCVVsss|||Alex|341234|asdasdUsadf|21444|||.....
```

I wanted to create a list of Person objects

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String id;
    String accessCode;
    String optionalID;

    // Getters and setters left out for brevity
}
```

Also I have a builder class to build it.

```
public String getParsed(String str) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String[] strSplit = str.split(Pattern.quote("|||"));
        List<Person> perList = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.stream(strSplit).forEach(item -> {
            String[] val = item.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
            if (val.length >= 2) {
                perList.add(PersonBuilder.asPerson()
                    .withName(val[0])
                    .withId(val[1])
                    .withAccessCode(val[3])
                    .withOptionalId(val.length > 2 ? val[3] : StringUtils.EMPTY)
                    .build());
            }
        });
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(perList)) {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(perList);
        }
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }
```

This code works. but Im wondering if there is a better way of doing this using Java 8. Also using index reference is a scary thing for me :)

Comment: The adding to `perList` seems useless, as it disappear at the end of the method vall

Comment: `getParsed` is presumably meant to build one or more `Person` instances, but its return type is `String`.

Comment: Is this code providing correct output?  You never refer `val[2]` which should be used for `accessCode` while `optionalId` is available for `val.length > 3`

Comment: why not use regex and groups ?

Comment: Well, this looks fairly good to me. Instead of `forEach` with the side-effect of adding to the array, however, I would `map` to a `Person` or `null`, `filter`ing out the `null`s, and then `collect(Collectors.toList())`. And the return type is peculiar.

Comment: @AlexRudenko I conver the list to a json string and return the string

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yes it does build and convert it to a json string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some cosmetic change is possible to replace `{...}` block with shorter `map / filter` stream methods instead of `forEach`:

```java
public String getParsed(String str) throws JsonProcessingException {

    List<Person> perList = Arrays.stream(str.split(Pattern.quote("|||")))
            .map(item -> item.split(Pattern.quote("|"))) // Stream<String[]>
            .filter(val -> val.length >= 3)
            .map(val -> PersonBuilder.asPerson()
                    .withName(val[0])
                    .withId(val[1])
                    .withAccessCode(val[2])
                    .withOptionalId(val.length > 3 ? val[3] : StringUtils.EMPTY)
                    .build()
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return perList.isEmpty() 
            ? StringUtils.EMPTY
            : mapper.writeValueAsString(perList);
}
```

However, if a valid JSON String should be returned from this method, it may be better to `return mapper.writeValueAsString(perList);` which supplies `"[]"` for an empty list instead of `""`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is pretty well. I just can only offer to make it a bit more efficient: not using streams and process the given `String` only once:

```java
public static List<Person> getPersons(String str) {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    int fromIndex = 0;

    while (true) {
        int index = str.indexOf('|', fromIndex);

        if (index < 0)
            queue.add(str.substring(fromIndex));
        else if (index != fromIndex)
            queue.add(str.substring(fromIndex, index));

        if (index < 0 || index == fromIndex) {
            String name = queue.remove();
            String id = queue.remove();
            String accessCode = queue.remove();
            String optionalID = queue.isEmpty() ? StringUtils.EMPTY : queue.remove();
            persons.add(new Person(name, id, accessCode, optionalID));

            if (index < 0)
                break;

            index++;
        }

        fromIndex = index + 1;
    }

    return persons;
}
```

***P.S.** Below is a bit complicated alternative solution, but it looks like OOP style. It uses custom `Iterator` to find `Person` in the given `String`.*

```java
public final class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final String id;
    private final String accessCode;
    private final String optionalId;

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    private Person(Builder builder) {
        name = builder.name;
        id = builder.id;
        accessCode = builder.accessCode;
        optionalId = builder.optionalId;
    }

    public static final class Builder {

        private String name;
        private String id;
        private String accessCode;
        private String optionalId = StringUtils.EMPTY;

        public Person build() {
            return new Person(this);
        }

        public Builder setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setAccessCode(String accessCode) {
            this.accessCode = accessCode;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setOptionalId(String optionalId) {
            this.optionalId = optionalId;
            return this;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", accessCode='" + accessCode + '\'' +
                ", optionalID='" + id + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```

```java
public final class PersonStream {

    public static Stream<Person> createFrom(String str) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
                new PersonIterator(str), Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
    }

    private PersonStream() {
    }

    private static final class PersonIterator implements Iterator<Person> {

        private final String str;
        private Person person;
        private int fromIndex;

        public PersonIterator(String str) {
            this.str = str;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return person != null || fromIndex >= 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Person next() {
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();

            if (person == null) {
                String name = readNextPart();
                String id = readNextPart();
                String accessCode = readNextPart();
                String optionalId = readNextPart();

                person = Person.builder()
                               .setName(name)
                               .setId(id)
                               .setAccessCode(accessCode)
                               .setOptionalId(optionalId)
                               .build();

                if (fromIndex >= 0)
                    fromIndex += optionalId == null ? 1 : 2;
            }

            try {
                return person;
            } finally {
                person = null;
            }
        }

        private String readNextPart() {
            int index = str.indexOf('|', fromIndex);

            if (index == fromIndex) {
                fromIndex++;
                return null;
            }

            try {
                return index < 0 ? str.substring(fromIndex)
                                 : str.substring(fromIndex, index);
            } finally {
                fromIndex = index < 0 ? -1 : index + 1;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

As result, the **Demo** will be very simple:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    String str = "james|12343|ascxZCCVVsss|||Alex|341234|asdasdUsadf|21444";
    PersonStream.createFrom(str).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted to *Build a list of Person objects* but your method is returning a String.  Perhaps I am either oversimplifying or not understanding what you want.  But here is what I came up with.  For this demo, I am using a Person record which is basically an immutable class.

```
record Person(
  String getName,
  String getId,
  String getAccessCode,
  String getOptionalID) {}
        
String s =
        "james|12343|ascxZCCVVsss|||Alex|341234|asdasdUsadf|21444";

List<Person> list = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\Q|||\\E"))
        .map(r->r.split("\\|"))
        .filter(arr->arr.length >= 3)
        .map(v->new Person(v[0], v[1], v[2], v.length == 4 ? v[3] : ""))
        .toList();

 list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
Person[getName=james, getId=12343, getAccessCode=ascxZCCVVsss, getOptionalID=]
Person[getName=Alex, getId=341234, getAccessCode=asdasdUsadf, getOptionalID=2144
4]
```